# Free graphics tools?

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a good free image editor](https://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor)

I am building android app and need some graphics tool for the background and to developer pixel character. Any good free graphics tools that can also be used in my commercial android app?

Comment: Gimp is not bad

Comment: Are you asking also for an image library to build into your app?

Answer (score 3):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) may also be an alternative for you. I personally find it a bit simpler to use than Gimp however it may lack some of the super "power user" features.

Additionally, when I do artwork for some stuff I prefer to use vector graphics so I can resize without loss of detail. For this, if I need a free tool, I use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en).

Comment: Paint.NET's simplicity is brilliant, Inkscape is great for SVG stuff, but I found it a little buggy on Win 7 when I was using it about 6-9 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try the GIMP - http://www.gimp.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use GIMP, been using it for a few months now and its quite good.